# Node.js / Use npm package twice

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, npm

I use `s3` npm package in order to upload file to S3.

In order to postponed delay of uploading files to S3, I want to create two pools of threads: the one will handle files that are greater than 650 MB, and the other will handle all files which are smaller or equal 650MB.

Here is the code I have:

```
var s3 = require('s3');
var client = s3.createClient({
            maxAsyncS3: 20, // this is the default
            s3RetryCount: 3, // this is the default
            s3RetryDelay: 1000, // this is the default
            multipartUploadThreshold: 209715200, // this is the default (20 MB)
            multipartUploadSize: 209715200, // this is the default (15 MB)
...

      var clientBig = s3.createClient({
            maxAsyncS3: 25,
            s3RetryCount: 3, // this is the default
            s3RetryDelay: 1000, // this is the default
            multipartUploadThreshold: 209715200, // this is the default (20 MB)
            multipartUploadSize: 209715200, // this is the default (15 MB)
```

And in function upload I get stat from `fs.stat`:

```
            if (stats != undefined && stats.size != undefined && stats.size > 650000000)
                    uploader = clientBig.uploadFile(params);
            else
                    uploader = client.uploadFile(params);
            //Upload file process..
```

The problem is that when I get files that are greater then 7GB, I saw that all the connection to S3 are occupied (because `maxAsyncS3` definition), and files that are smaller then 650MB are still waiting for free connections, even thought it is in other package (and have it own `maxAsyncS3` definition)

Comment: From what I can tell in looking at the `node-s3-client` code, each client object is completely separate from a `maxAsyncS3` point of view.  The actual limitation is managed by separate instances of `node-pend` which don't appear to know anything about one another.  I wonder if what you're running into is a node.js total socket limit instead.  Have you tried raising the node.js global socket limit?

Comment: @jfriend00: No, what is the default limit? I can't find information about it in the net.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649972/how-to-set-maximum-http-client-connections-in-node-js