# node.js server limiting new connections

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, tcp, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using node.js to create a server that is used for sending server-sent events to the clients. I'm running the server on a Windows 7 machine.

The way I connect is by sending HTTP get requests with apache httpclient, establish TCP connection and receive the events from the server. What I notice is that after I connect 11 clients at the same time, the previous connections close.

Is there a limit in Node.js? Or is this system-specific? I've been googling about this and I couldn't find anything.

Here is a sample code from the requests I'm sending:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); 

String domain =    "..."; 

HttpUriRequest httpGet = new HttpGet(domain); String encoding = "..."

httpGet.setHeader(new BasicHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding)); 
httpGet.setHeader(new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "text/event-stream")); 

HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(httpGet); 
HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity(); 

if (resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200){ String 
   responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity, "UTF-8"); 
   System.out.println(responseString); 
}
```

and I'm doing this many times in my test code.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Inb4 it's the default connection limit on the http client or the system-wide limit of the number of file descriptions

Comment: wich version of node? do you close the HTTP request and open a new tcp or just maintain a long pool HTTP request? please add more details of your setup

Comment: @JohnKiller , I'm using v0.12.2. I'm sending the request, open a new tcp connection and maintain it. From what I understand, the client terminates the connection, because I have other clients connecting (e.g. by postman) and these connections never close.

Comment: @JohnKiller, sorry I can't format it properly... :-)

Comment: edit your question instead of writing in comments

Comment: i think this is a client problem. can you try on 2 computers simultaneously?

Comment: @JohnKiller, I tried with new instances of the test code and it works. It is client issue, I presume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since node js v0.12 the `http.globalAgent.maxSockets` has been set to `Infinity`, so it is a client side problem.

This should set the limit for the client side:

```
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 1000;
```

Another option is to pass an `Agent` object to the http request. Have a look at this other question: [How to set maximum http client connections in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649972/how-to-set-maximum-http-client-connections-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this property and see if it helps you:

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets

Depending on the version of Node.js you're using, it may be limiting the amount of open connections. Try raising it:

```
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 128; // or whatever suits your app
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help!

I'm using v0.12.2. I added this property, as well, that you mentioned, but from I understand this property is set to "Infinity" by default.

Comment: @Guiness It depends on the version of Node.js that you're using. What is it?

Comment: It's v0.12.2, which has the "Infinity" set, I think. It was a client problem, I tried with different instances and it worked. Thanks, Lucio!